# Is it ok to nest ConsumerWidgets in riverpods?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

In Riverpods, is it ok to nest ConsumerWidgets?  Something like this? I want to do so to keep my apis separated, but it feels like it might slow down performance?

```
class Foo1 extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, ScopedReader watch) {
    // watch something
    return Container(
      child: Foo2(),
    );
  }
}

class Foo2 extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
    // watch something
  Widget build(BuildContext context, ScopedReader watch) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you listening to the same provider in every `ConsumerWidget`?

Comment: no, different ones. for example, details could be for Foo1 and comments for Foo2. but as an alternate, I was thinking. I could the data for details and comments into 1 provider, but that felt not as clean. do you have any thoughts @7mada?

Comment: That would be fine, if you want to use 1 provider you can use it with scoped provider to filter rebuilds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is completely and totally fine. It would not be strange if most or all widgets in your application were ConsumerWidgets.

As long as you only watch providers when/where needed, you have nothing to be concerned about.

There are many ways to optimize rebuilds. For example, creating providers that only expose one aspect of state your widget may depend on or using [Consumer](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/reading/#consumer) to only rebuild certain children when the value exposed by a provider changes. If you're using [hooks](https://pub.dev/packages/hooks_riverpod), you can use [select](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/reading#useprovider-hooks_riverpod-only) which is super handy for conditionally rebuilding.